# No result from fetchAll();

Tags: php, mysql

I'm totally a newbie in the world of PHP and MySQL. I am reading the book of Kevin Yank and while doing one of his examples, I encountered a weird outcome. I'm sure I followed and typed correctly the code written on his book but I wondered why I'm not getting the same result. I've checked the code back and forth and sure that it is right or maybe I'm missing something.

I'm posting this here because I know a lot from here are very helpful and very kind to starters like me. Any inputs are highly appreciated. Looking forward for comments so that I can proceed with my studies because I think I am stuck because of this weird error.

Please see below code for your reference.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Joke CMS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Joke Management System</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="jokes/">Manage Jokes</a></li>
        <li><a href="authors/">Manage Authors</a></li>
        <li><a href="categories/">Manage Joke Categories</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

//Display author list
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
try {
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM author');
} catch (PDOException $e){
    $error = 'Error fetching authors from database! ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
} 

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Delete')
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
        //Get jokes belonging to author
        try {
            $sql = 'SELECT id FROM joke WHERE authorid = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $error = 'Error fetching authors with their jokes! ' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        $result = $s->fetchAll();

        //Delete joke category entries
        try {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM jokecategory WHERE jokeid = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            //For each joke
            foreach ($result as $row)
                {
                    $jokeId = $row['id'];
                    $s->bindValue(':id', $jokeId);
                    $s->execute();
                }
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $error = 'Error deleting joke category! ' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        //Delete jokes belonging to author
        try {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM joke WHERE authorid = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $error = 'Error deleting joke from a specific author! ' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        //Delete the author
        try {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM author WHERE id = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            $error = 'Error deleting the author from database! ' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        header('Location: .');
        exit();
    }

foreach ($result as $row){
    $authors[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name']
        ); 
} 

include 'authors.html.php';
?>
```

**authors.html.php**

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/helper.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Manage Authors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Manage Authors</h1>
    <p><a href="?add">Add new author</a></p>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($authors as $author): ?>
            <li>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div>
                        <?php echo htmlout($author['name']); ?>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlout($author['id']); ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="..">Return to JMS home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

All inputs are highly apprecited.

Comment: What is the outcome? What are you expecting to see and what do you see?

Comment: just asking to be sure ; is your database filled with data ?

Comment: @AdRock: I'm sorry for being vague here, actually the outcome is just a blank page. I wonder why there isn't atleast an error even if I have a **catch** statement after every query.

Comment: @KarelG: yes, database are filled with data.

Comment: try replacing the 'and' in this line with && if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Delete')

Comment: @AdRock: already did what you suggested and still the same result. The author entry is still not deleted. Do you have any idea what went wrong or am I missing something? Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- I'm not gonna ask if the `$pdo` object is properly initialized and if you have actual records in the database. You test queries with an external MySQL client like Workbench. You use it to optimize too. Only when you are satisfied with a query, you put it in your script, unless it's so simple you can write it properly in place.
- Escape `` `table_names` `` and `` `column_names` `` to be MySQL legit and also end queries with a `;`. And it looks better.
- Also, before `foreach` initialize the variable `$authors = array();`. That book should teach you that.
- Learn to use `var_dump()`. Put `var_dump($result);` after `$result = $pdo->query('...');`. Also use `var_dump($row);` in the `foreach`. It's used for simple but effective debugging. Prints variable values.
- `htmlout()` does exist?
- What do you actually see after the `var_dump()`s added around?

Comment: `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(27) "SELECT id, name FROM author" }`

It's what displays on the screen after putting `var_dump()`
Actually, this is my first time to hear of that code `var_dump()`

Comment: @Karl I don't know what to say. In a desperate attempt, consider moving the end `foreach` right after its query. And see if the `$authors` contains anything after the `foreach` with a `var_dump`. I personally use `mysqli` and not `PDO` so I don't know its gotchas.

Comment: thank you for your help, I figured out what am missing on this code. I am missing the `name="id"` on the **authors.html.php**. The code should be `<input type="hidden" **name="id"** value="<?php htmlout($author['id']; ?>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

In your authors.html.php file, you didn't give your hidden input type a name

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlout($author['id']); ?>"/>
```

try changing to

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlout($author['id']); ?>"/>
```

Your are looking for a POST variable which doesn't exist

```
$s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
```